# How do I split a table column into new columns from the nth delimiter onwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed to create some code that splits, at the slash delimiter, the third column into new columns.

What I did not manage to do is make it split from the nth (i.e. 2nd) occurrence onwards.
I could not find a similar question on the internet, that's why I post i here.

The desired outcome should be as follows:

[image]

```js
 function split() {
     var delimiter = "/";
     var arr = [];
     var highest = 0;
     var columnIndex = "";
     $('#tbl td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
         ColumnIndex = $(this).index();
         var string = $(this).text();
         var array = string.split(delimiter);
         var nbrCharacter = (string.split(delimiter).length - 1) //COUNT OCCURENCES OF CHARACTER
         var temp = (nbrCharacter > highest) ? highest++ : highest = highest;
         arr.push(string.split(delimiter));
     });
     for (i = 0; i < highest; i++) { //ADD EMPTY COLUMNS
         $('#tbl').find('tr').each(function() {
             $(this).find('td').eq(ColumnIndex).after('<td></td>');
         });
     }
     for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { //POPULATE CELLS FROM ARRAY
         var columnTracker = ColumnIndex
         for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
             $('#tbl').find('tr:eq(' + (i + 1) + ')').find('td:eq(' + columnTracker + ')').html(arr[i][j]);
             columnTracker++
         }
     }
 }
```

```css
th {
    height: 15px;
    min-width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Courier, monospace;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}

td {
    height: 15px;
    min-width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Courier, monospace;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="split()">Split</button>

<br>
<br>
<table id="tbl">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tbl-header">
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A/B/C</td>
            <td>B/C</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A/B</td>
            <td>B/C</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>D/E</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A/B/C/D</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>C/D/E</td>
            <td>D/E/F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>B/C/D</td>
            <td>C/D</td>
            <td>D/E/F/G</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A/B/C</td>
            <td>B/C/D/E</td>
            <td>C/D/E/F</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would strongly urge you to separate your data model from your presentation model, so that you don't combine the logic that splits up the data with your HTML / DOM traversal code

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean..

Comment: I mean that you should create a data structure that represents your data *independently of its markup*, then write a function that manipulates the data into the desired form, and only then write another function that converts that data structure into HTML.